# Challenge with jmeter for asp.net application?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Could someone please help me with the challenge that we can face for asp.net application using jmeter. I am preparing POC for Performance testing and i have to mention the challenges with jmeter for asp.net application.

Answer (score -1):

Challenges with Jmeter for Asp.net application

1. Difficult to trace the dynamics values for co-relations
2. Add the Authorization and authentication header issues
3. cookies and compression header issues
4. Proxy challenges